# reRender Page Block Sections Based on Selected Value of a selectList

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, selectlist, selectoption

I am creating a Visualforce page and I have a section where I want to add in a Select List with three values and based on the value that is selected I want it to display a specific Page Block Section on the page and I just cannot seem to get it to work. I think I am very close and that I am just missing something and would appreciate any and all help.

Here is the Visualforce code

```
<apex:page controller="CommunityQuoteNowController" showHeader="true" sidebar="false" lightningStylesheets="true">
        
        <apex:outputPanel id="messagePanel">
            <apex:pageMessages />
        </apex:outputPanel>
        
        <!-- Quote Now Form -->
        <apex:form id="quoteNowForm" >
            <apex:pageBlock title="Quote Now">
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!GetRates}" value="Get Rates"/>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!clearPage}" value="Clear" />
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageBlockSection >
                    <apex:inputField label="Customer Profile" value="{!load.rtms__Customer__c}" />
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedMode}" title="Select" multiselect="false" size="1" id="selectModes" label="Mode">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!ModesList}" />
                    </apex:selectList>
                    <apex:inputField label="Total Weight" value="{!load.rtms__Total_Weight__c}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Details" columns="2">
                    <apex:inputField label="Ship Date" value="{!load.rtms__Order_Date__c}" />
                    <apex:inputField label="Payment Terms" value="{!load.rtms__Payment_Terms__c}" />
                    <apex:inputField label="Origin Zip Code" value="{!originStop.rtms__Postal_Code__c}" />
                    <apex:inputField label="Destination Zip Code" value="{!destinationStop.rtms__Postal_Code__c}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <hr />
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedFreightDetail}" title="freightDetails" multiselect="false" size="1" id="selectFreightDetails" label="Freight Details" >
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!FreightDetails}" />
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="freightDetailsWrapper" />
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:outputPanel layout="none" id="freightDetailsWrapper" >
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" id="ClassAndWeight" rendered="{!IF(selectedFreightDetail != 'Class_and_Weight',True,False)}">
                        <apex:repeat value="{!lineItems}" var="items">
                            <apex:inputField label="NMFC Class" value="{!items.rtms__NMFC_Class__c}"/>
                            <apex:inputField label="Weight (lbs)" value="{!items.rtms__Weight__c}"/>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4" id="Density"  rendered="{!IF(selectedFreightDetail = 'Density',True,False)}">
                        <apex:repeat value="{!lineItems}" var="items">
                            <apex:inputField label="Length (in)" value="{!items.rtms__Length__c}"/>
                            <apex:inputField label="Width (in)" value="{!items.rtms__Width__c}"/>
                            <apex:inputField label="Height (in)" value="{!items.rtms__Height__c}"/>
                            <apex:inputField label="Weight (lbs)" value="{!items.rtms__Weight__c}"/>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3" id="Pallet" rendered="{!IF(selectedFreightDetail = 'Pallet',True,False)}">
                        <apex:repeat value="{!lineItems}" var="items">
                            <apex:inputField label="Handling Units" value="{!items.rtms__Handling_Units__c}"/>
                            <apex:inputField label="Handling Unit Count" value="{!items.rtms__Handling_Unit_Count__c}"/>
                            <apex:inputField label="Weight (lbs)" value="{!items.rtms__Weight__c}"/>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:commandButton value="Add Line Item" Action="{!AddRow}" immediate="true" id="addRowButton"/>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    
    </apex:page>
```

And here is my controller

```
public class CommunityQuoteNowController {

// Variables
public rtms__Load__c load { get; set; }
public rtms__Stop__c originStop { get; set; }
public rtms__Stop__c destinationStop { get; set; }
public List<rtms__Load__c> loadList { get; set; }
public List<rtms__LineItem__c> lineItems { get; set; }
public String selectedMode { get; set; }
public List<SelectOption> availableModes { get; set; }
public String selectedFreightDetail { get; set; }
public List<SelectOption> options { get; set; }


public rtms__Load__c getLoad() {
    return load;
}

public CommunityQuoteNowController() {
    load = new rtms__Load__c();
    originStop = new rtms__Stop__c();
    destinationStop = new rtms__Stop__c();
    lineItems = new List<rtms__LineItem__c>();
    AddRow();
    getModesList();
}

public PageReference AddRow() {
    lineItems.add(new rtms__LineItem__c());
    return null;
}

public List<selectOption> getModesList() {
    List<rtms__Mode__c> modes = new List<rtms__Mode__c>();

    modes = [Select Id,name from rtms__Mode__c];

    List<SelectOption> availableModes = new List<SelectOption>();

    availableModes.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));

    for(rtms__Mode__c m : modes) {
        availableModes.add(new SelectOption(m.Id,m.Name));
    }
    return availableModes;
}

public List<selectOption> getFreightDetails() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    options.add(new SelectOption('Class_and_Weight','Class and Weight'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Density','Density'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Pallet','Pallet'));

    return options;
}

/* Attempt at displaying a total weight for line items
public Decimal getTotalWeight(){
    Decimal totalWeight = 0;
    for(rtms__LineItem__c li : lineItems) {
        totalWeight += (li.rtms__Weight__c);
    }
    return totalWeight;
} */

public PageReference clearPage() {
    PageReference newpage = new PageReference(System.currentPageReference().getURL());
    newPage.getParameters().clear();
    newpage.setRedirect(true);
    return newpage;
}

public PageReference GetRates() {
    load.rtms__Mode__c = selectedMode;
    upsert load;
    
    if(load != null) {
        originStop.rtms__Load__c = load.Id;
        originStop.rtms__Number__c = 1;
        originStop.rtms__Is_Pickup__c = True;
        upsert originStop;
    }
    
    if(load != null) {
        destinationStop.rtms__Load__c = load.Id;
        destinationStop.rtms__Number__c = 2;
        destinationStop.rtms__Is_Dropoff__c = True;
        upsert destinationStop;
    }
    
    List<rtms__LineItem__c> items = new List<rtms__LineItem__c>();
    if(load != null) {
        for(rtms__LineItem__c i : lineItems) {
            i.rtms__Load__c = load.Id;
            i.Name = 'Line Item From Quote';
            i.rtms__Item_Description__c = 'From Quote';
            i.rtms__Pickup_Stop__c = originStop.Id;
            i.rtms__Delivery_Stop__c = destinationStop.Id;
            items.add(i);
        }
    }
    if(items != null) { 
        upsert lineItems;
   }
   return null;
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at your code wherever you are loading the select options (i.e., filter values). For example,

```
options.add(new SelectOption('','Class and Weight'));
options.add(new SelectOption('','Density'));
options.add(new SelectOption('','Pallet'));
```

The `label` string in the constructor definition `SelectOption(value, label)` is displayed as one of the filter options to the user and `value` string is returned to the controller when the user selects an option. In your code, you are passing a valid `label` string, but an empty string for all `value`. So when you select an option, empty value is passed back to the controller.

Now, look the `apex:pageBlockSection` code. For example,

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" id="ClassAndWeight" rendered="{!IF(selectedFreightDetail = 'Class And Weight',True,False)}">
```

Since, your filter selection passed back an empty string, `selectedFreightDetail` will hold this empty value and the ***IF*** condition in `apex:pageBlockSection` will always evaluate to false. Hence, the re-rendering of the component doesn't display anything.

***Note:*** Ensure that the `value` string passed to `SelectOption` constructor and value used in the `apex:pageBlockSection` match exactly (case sensitively). As a best practice, don't use spaces in the `value` strings and replace them with `_` (or anything other char of your choice).

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing this out. I was sure that I was missing something small. I updated the values for the Select Options and then copy and pasted them into the appropriate Page Section reRenders but they are still not loading so I feel like maybe I am missing something else. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Could you post the update code snippet? Have you checked if `lineItems` is populated before you change the filter value? Easiest way is to remove the **IF** condition in `pageBlockSection` and check if you are able to see all the block sections with values populated.

Comment: Okay, I updated all of my code in the original post.

Comment: Also, I updated the code within the IF's to say selectedFreightDetail = Null instead of the values and they all loaded in. So that variable is still not getting a value.... Any thoughts @arut ?

Comment: Your code works fine in my dev org (_Although, I had to comment out a lot of code and retain only the code relevant to filter options and page block section; and use `Account` object instead of `rtms__LineItem__c`_). Based the following line in your code `{!IF(selectedFreightDetail != 'Class_and_Weight',True,False)}`, the _Class and Weight_ block is always displayed, while the other 2 sections are toggled based on user selection. **Are none of the page block sections displayed for you (regardless of change in selected filter option)?**

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want... I wonder why it is not working for me... You didn't have to change anything else other than commenting out the other items? **Yes, nothing for me appears regardless of the selection**

Comment: Yes. All I did was comment out all the pageBlockSection before `<hr />` tag in the VF page and commented out all the apex code except the constructor, 2 methods (AddRow & getFreightDetails) and 3 variables (lineItems, selectedFreightDetail, options). BTW, I've only checked this in preview mode. I guess it should work fine everywhere (if it works fine in preview). Can you comment out the other lines of code and check? That will rule out the possibility of issue with other lines of code.

Comment: So, when I comment out everything else. Nothing loads when I first load the page, but when I change it to Density then that block does load, but when I try and go back to one of the other options it throws an error on one of the required fields in that section and will not allow the other block to load. So, two issues, something else in my code must be breaking it and it appears to not be allowing me to switch between the selections

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115316/discussion-between-arut-and-cmmoutes13).